# Pass localStorage of google map place as map center in new window

Tags: javascript, html, json, google-maps, local-storage

We have an input field and submit on a popup with this template:

```
<input type="text" size="50" placeholder="Your adventure is waiting!" id="mapitplace" /> 
<input type="submit" value="Map It!" id="mapitsubmit"/>
```

And JS:

```
function MapItUp() {
  var mapitplace = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById('mapitplace'));
  localStorage.mapitupp = mapitplace;
  jQuery('#mapitsubmit').click(function(){
  location.href = "http://roadtripsharing.com/map-it";
  });
  return false;
}
```

For an example you can click "Map It!" in the steering wheel at roadtripsharing.com to display the popup, type a place in the text input and click the green Map It! button. The button opens the new location /map-it with

```
<div id="mapitmap"></div>
```

and

```
function initMapIt() {
    var mapit = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapitmap'), {
      center: {lat: 39, lng: -105},
      zoom: 3,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    if (localStorage.mapitupp !== null){
      var mapitupp = localStorage.mapitupp;
      var mapittupp = mapitupp.getplace();  
      if (mapittupp.geometry.viewport) {
        mapit.fitBounds(mapittupp.geometry.viewport);
      }
      else {
        mapit.setCenter(mapittupp.geometry.location);
        mapit.setZoom(17);  
      }
    console.log(mapittupp);
    }
}
```

initMapIt is loading as indicated by the rendering of the map at zoom 3. Not seeing a console log of mapitupp or any evidence it is being passed.

There is a console error on /map-it:

(index):1102 Uncaught ReferenceError: mapitupp is not defined

Substituting mapittupp=localStorage.mapitupp.getplace(); for mapittupp=mapitupp.getplace(); gives the console error (also on /map-it):

(index):1102 Uncaught TypeError: localStorage.mapitupp.getplace is not a function

I have read q's and a's about JSON stringify and parsing but I am attempting to pass a string (mapitupp or localStorage.mapitupp not sure the correct way to say it but it should have the value of the text field #mapitplace.

Can you help with the syntax of saving the variable mapitupp in localstorage on the first page and then retrieving it to convert to a place object and make it the center of the new map opened in #mapitmap?

Comment: what is the value of `localStorage.mapitupp` ?

Comment: i would like to store the value mapitplace.getPlace(); however if it is easier to pass mapitplace which is a text string maybe that's a better idea?

Comment: No,I'm asking what is the value it returns here `mapitplace.getPlace()` ? Is that `boolean` value ?

Comment: edited question to pass string variable mapitupp via localStorage, test against null value of mapitupp and then perform getplace() in initMapIt function on /map-it page to get the Google Place object mapittupp. However I'm still getting a console error as shown in the updated question.

Comment: How can you access the local variable `mapitplace` which is in the `MapItUp` from the `initMapIt` function ? which is wrong.That is why it gave above error.

Comment: i thought that's what localStorage does, lets functions relating to different pages pass variables between each other

Comment: I'm talking about this `mapittupp=mapitupp.getplace(); `.Where you have defined those variables ?

Comment: Edited question to attempt to define them. Thanks. I'll independently try a simpler example of passing strings and attempt this when i have a better handle at it or get more hints on how to pass the values from one function to another.

Comment: is `var mapitplace = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById('mapitplace'));` return a `Json object` or what ?

Comment: i thought it was just a string but i guess it's an object according to this: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete#add_autocomplete. so i'm not sure how to pass it with localStorage.

Comment: why do you need to store it on the `localStorage` ?

Comment: not sure, it just seemed like i had to use it because the button is loading a new page (going from site home to the "Map It!" page. if there's another way to open the new page with a map centered with the place from the autocomplete on the original page, that's what i'm trying to achieve but from my research it seemed that localStorage or cookies were necessary and i wanted to use localStorage.

Answer (score 0):

According to this `localStorage.mapitupp = mapitplace.getPlace();` the `localStorage` value should be a `string`.

So then how can you use it like this `if (localStorage.mapitupp){` ? To use it like that `localStorage.mapitupp` must be a `True/False` value.So your problem is on that place.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to pass a place object through localStorage wasn't working. My solution was to pass the place_id string instead.

```
function MapItUp() {
  var mapitplace = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById('mapitplace'));
jQuery('#mapitsubmit').click(function(){
var mappitplace = mapitplace.getPlace();
var placetopass = mappitplace.place_id;
localStorage.setItem('placetopass', placetopass);
location.href = "http://roadtripsharing.com/map-it";
}); 
return false;
}
```

and to get it and use in the map:

```
function initMapIt() {    
  var mapit = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapitmap'), {
    center: {lat: 39, lng: -105},
    zoom: 6,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});  
  if (localStorage.placetopass !== null){
    var rtsgeocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder;
    var rtsinfowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;
    var newplace = localStorage.getItem('placetopass');
    rtsgeocoder.geocode({'placeId': newplace}, function(results, status) {
if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
  if (results[0]) {
    mapit.setZoom(11);
    mapit.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
    var rtsmarker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: mapit,
      position: results[0].geometry.location
    });
    rtsinfowindow.setContent(results[0].formatted_address+'<p>Yeah, buddy!</p>');
    rtsinfowindow.open(mapit, rtsmarker);
  } else {
    window.alert('No results found');
  }
} else {
  window.alert('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);
}
});
}
else {

}
}
```